# What's the formula for partitions where each group has a different size?

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking at this formula[image]

My understanding is that the number of partitions is equal to that formula, but only when the order of the partitions matters. eg, That's right, if you can only have $n_1$ in the first group and $n_2$ in the second group and so on.

My understanding is that if the order of the groups does not matter, then it is the same formula except you add $r!$ to the denominator because you need to account for the different orderings that can achieve that result.

Is that right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Does the denominator need to add up to n in the first case?

Comment: Yes, you need $\sum_{i=1}^r n_i = n$ since the sizes of the blocks must add up to the size of the set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct. If all the groups are different sizes, then the answer is $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\dots n_r!}$ regardless whether you care about the order of the groups. It cannot be the case that you divide by $r!$, since for example when $n=3,n_1=1,n_2=2$, then $\frac{3!}{1!2!}=3$ is not divisible by $2!$.

If all groups are the *same* size, the you do need to add $r!$ to the denominator to discount for order, so the formula is $\frac{n!}{r!(n/r)!^r}$.

In general, suppose the numbers $n_i$ are partitioned into several groups, where the $k^{th}$ group has size $\lambda_k$, and the $n_i=n_j$ if and only if $n_i$ and $n_j$ are in the same group. Then the number of ways to partition the objects into groups of size $n_1,\dots,n_r$ without respect to order is
$$
\frac{n!}{\left(\prod_{i=1}^r n_i!\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^m \lambda_j!\right)}.
$$

Comment: Of course, you are right.